# ggplot Histogram issues in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the following code in R shiny (in Server.R) to get a histogram output.

```
 output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
       newdata <- subset(indooriv,seris_id=='2')
     ggplot(newdata, aes(x=isc),environment = environment()) + geom_histogram()

          })
```

But it keeps giving me the following error.

```
Error in exists(name, envir = env, mode = mode) : 
  argument "env" is missing, with no default
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: for what you need `,environment = environment()` in ggplot?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error, this works fine for me:

```
library(shiny)
data(iris)

u.n <-  as.character(unique(iris$Species))
names(u.n) <- u.n

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('species','Species',choices =u.n)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('distPlot')  
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    newdata <- subset(iris, iris$Species==input$species)
    ggplot(newdata, aes(x=Sepal.Width),environment = environment()) + geom_histogram()
  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server = server)
```

If there's no specific reason to call environment I wouldn't do that.